# Finding position of element after orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios

I am wandering if there is a way in which you could know what is going to be an UI element's frame after rotation. I need this in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` in order to set other element relative to this one.

In this method , if you check the frame of an UI element , it will be the frame before the rotation since it's called `WILLrotate...`

I know I can do this in `didRotate...` , but that would look bad . I want to set the new frames in an animation while the screen is rotating. I know I can just hardcode the values but that doesn't look like much of a solution.

Cheers,

George

Comment: I mean how can you determine BEFORE the rotation , the frame that a view will have AFTER rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do it. If you know the "springs and struts" that you see in Interface Builder - well they are bits in a bitmask for the "autoresizingMask" property of your primary view. Since you know your view is going to change its frame, you can take any arbitrary view in the primary view's subviews (and those views subviews), and starting from the primary view, work your way down determining what each container's frame will be after the rotation.

For example, if you have a UITextField with frame 10,460,300,10, and it has a horizontal spring, and is anchored to the left, right, and bottom - then when the view rotates from a width of say 320 to 480, then the new frame will be 10,300,460,10.

Comment: Hi David , thank you for the quick answer. I know about the `autoresizingMask`...for a while I've been writing my code without using IB (personal preference). I don't know why I haven't thought of geting the bits in the bitmask and go from there :P. Thank you again.

Comment: One of the biggest problems more experienced developers have is getting stuck in a dead end street - it happens to me all the time. How many times have you had a problem, you go to a co-worker, explain it, then half way through see the solution, turn to co-worker, and say "Thanks so much for your help - now I see the solution" :-)